# NSOutlineView and Core Data 1 → Many Relationships

Tags: swift, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nsarraycontroller

I have a Core Data model that supports a 1 → Many relationship (1 Folder to many Phrases). At the moment I'm just displaying the Phrases on a flat `NSTableView` using Core Data Bindings to a `NSArrayController` to glue everything together - this is working happily.

I'm trying to experiment with an `NSOutlineView` to achieve the same result but showing the folders as well. I've tried a similar binding structure that I'm already using with the `NSTableView` but I'm not making any headway. What steps should I take to move from a flat `NSTableView` to a `NSOutlineView` with 'depth'?

Here's my MOM:
[image: managed object model. We spell mother 'mum' in New Zealand, so not as funny as it could have been.]

Top level folders, bottom level phrases. No nesting. I'm not an animal.

NSTreeController

- I have a `NSTreeController` bound to the array controller for `arrangedObjects` on `Controller Content`
- It is set to 'Entity Name' mode with an entity name of `Folder` (this feels wrong)
- `phrases` is set to the children key path
- Prepares Content is true
- It's mOC is set to a valid mOC

NSOutlineView

- Outline View Content is bound to the Tree Controller using arrangedObjects as the Key and string as the Key Path

The Phrase NSManagedObject

- has an extension called 'phrases' which returns an empty set, since it'll never have children.

When I do this, I get this as a result:

> [APPNAME.Folder copyWithZone:]:

The [tutorial that got me this far](https://lifeasclay.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/connecting-nsoutlineview-to-core-data-in-10-6-part-1-ordered-trees/) had nested objects and only one type of entity, where as I have two. What do I need to have an accurate representation of my core data objects in a `NSOutlineView`?

Comment: How far did you get? Do you use NSTreeController?

Comment: Yeah - I tried to implement as suggested here: https://lifeasclay.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/connecting-nsoutlineview-to-core-data-in-10-6-part-1-ordered-trees/ but I had all sorts of problems with managed objects complaining they weren't key value compliant. I was worried this was because I only want two levels - folders and phrases (in folders).

Comment: Did you see [How to create SourceList to show Core Data ToMany relations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243984/how-to-create-sourcelist-to-show-core-data-tomany-relations)?

Comment: No - but the question seems a bit different to mine. Should I use a `NSTreeController` with Phrase as the leaf node, and display in an `NSOutlineView`?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTreeController` and `NSOutlineView` work in the same way as `NSTableView` and `NSArrayController`. To use `NSTreeController` you don't need a `NSArrayController`, you can put the treecontroller in entity mode.

> my entities are not called Table View Cell

Remove the column binding, it is for cell based ouline views. Bind the content of the outline view to the tree controller and bind the text fields in the Table View Cells to the Table Cell View.

> The tutorial that got me this far had nested objects and only one type of entity, where as I have two.

This is a problem because `NSTreeController` has only one `childrenKeyPath` and the textfield in the outline view can only bind with one key. As far as I know there are two workarounds.

Solution 1: Create a subclass of `NSTreeController` and override

```
- (NSString *)childrenKeyPathForNode:(NSTreeNode *)node
```

the managed object is `node.representedObject`.
Implement the delegate method `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` and use a different view for each entity.

Solution 2: Create `NSManagedObject` subclasses and implement calculated properties for children and display so all entities answer to the same keys.
I think this solution feels wrong, managed objects shouldn't contain code for views, but it is very easy to implement if you already have `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: Cool- thank you I will work through this tomorrow. If I renamed Folder.foldername to Folder.string (so the display value on the folder and phrase entities has the same property name) would that make life easier?

Comment: Yes, the binding of the text field will be the same key for both entities.

Comment: Hi @Willeke, I've updated my question to reflect changes you suggest - not quite there but maybe it's a small change or I've missed something.

Comment: Remove the arraycontroller. Phrase.phrases can return nil but an empty set shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I have removed the array controller - just using the NSTreeController as you suggested. Does Folder need to have all the same properties as Phrase (maybe this is why it is failing copyWithZone:)?

Comment: When and where do you get "[APPNAME.Folder copyWithZone:]:"? Is the outline view view based or cell based?

Comment: It was view based, changing it to cell based stop the errors and shows a disclosure icon (with blank, but editable text). https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnsqv6nfhjqdn75/Screenshot%202016-03-18%2005.27.31.png?dl=0