# NSOutlineView with NSTreeController bindings with core data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, binding, nsoutlineview

Please send me some links on how to use NSOutlineView with NSTreeController bindings ***with*** using core data.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/em7kxjqmxqjto88/outlineViewCoreData%20copie.zip?dl=0 this example is ok

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1asg3kkf9ltwj2w/outlineViewCoreData.zip?dl=0
this example is ko. ==> why

the entity EntityCategory is not key value coding-compliant for the key "category".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=nstreecontroller%20nsoutlineview%20core%20data

Comment: I have already looked, but I did not find anything very interesting

Comment: [NSOutlineView and Core Data 1 → Many Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993114/nsoutlineview-and-core-data-1-%e2%86%92-many-relationships).

Comment: I do not go out why in my example      I have the entity EntityCategory is not key value coding-compliant for the key "category". it's a nsset

Comment: `EntityCategory` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. The problem is: `NSTreeController` has only one childrenKeyPath for all obhects.

Comment: if there is a problem, there is surely a solution
How to solve the problem ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

All is ok

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnh0e0atwmrqpmm/outlineViewCoreDataOK.zip?dl=0

i have add

```
extension EntityCategory {

    @objc var  children : NSSet {
        return []
    }
    
    @objc var count : Int {
        return 0
    }
    
    @objc var isLeaf : Int {
        return 1
    }
    
}
```

and

```
extension EntityAffectation {

    @objc var  children : NSSet {
        return category!
    }

    @objc var count : Int {
        return category!.count
    }

    @objc var isLeaf : Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

and

[image]